# Dismiss popover viewController when tapped elsewhere

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I'm presenting a popover viewController on top of a UITableView. How can i dismiss this popover when tapped outside of it? I'm trying to call it from the didSelectRow method, but the tap isn't detected. Any suggestion?
Thanks!
this is my code:

```
    let addFriendsPopoverViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomePopOver") as! HomePopOverViewController
    addFriendsPopoverViewController.index = (sender.tag)!
    addFriendsPopoverViewController.delegate = self
    addFriendsPopoverViewController.isModalInPopover = true
    addFriendsPopoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle =   UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
    addFriendsPopoverViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 210, height: 40)
    let popoverMenuViewController = addFriendsPopoverViewController.popoverPresentationController
    popoverMenuViewController!.permittedArrowDirections = .down
    popoverMenuViewController!.delegate = self
    popoverMenuViewController!.sourceView = self.view
    popoverMenuViewController!.sourceRect = CGRect(
        x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width  - 105,
        y: 50,
        width: 1,
        height: 1)
    present(
        addFriendsPopoverViewController,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil)
```

Comment: How are you presenting the popover?

Comment: i'm presenting it from a button in the tableView. (when this button is tapped)

Comment: What's the presentation code?

Comment: I just edited my post. Check it out please!

Comment: Don't set `isModalInPopover` to `true` if you want it to dismiss when tapping outside.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 4):

A view controller presented in a `UIPopoverController`, or presented using `UIModalPresentationPopover`, will automatically be dismissed when the user taps outside the popover, unless you have set `isModalInPopover` or implemented the delegate method which prevents it.

If you need some code to run when this happens, then you'll need to implement a delegate method too.

Which specific methods depend on whether you're using a `UIPopoverController` or `UIModalPresentationPopover`.  The tags on your question suggest the former, but that's quite an old-fashioned (and deprecated) way of doing it.

Comment: Yes it is a UIModalPresentationPopover. How can i detect touch outside of it and dismiss it?

Comment: @MarcIbrahim why do you need to detect touches outside of it?  It will dismiss automatically.

Comment: This is the problem. It's not dismissing automatically!

Comment: You're setting `isModalInPopover` to true - don't do that!

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have found your answer, I wanted to share my solution because I had the same problem and after I spent some time to figure it out, I have found what the problem was. It was not actually because of something missing but because of something is implemented in vain.

Although I don't know why it happens but if following method implemented in your code, that may cause popover **not** to dismiss by tapping anywhere else than `UIBarButtonItem` itself.

```
    func prepareForPopoverPresentation(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) {
        popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = .any
        popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: categoryButton)
    }
```

Here's the rest of implementation I have made for popover:

```
extension SearchViewController:UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}

func presentPopover(sender: UIButton) {
    let popoverContentController = PopoverCategoryViewController()
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: popoverContentController)
    nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
    nav.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    let popover = nav.popoverPresentationController
    popover?.backgroundColor = ChaptifyColor.backgroundGray
    popover?.delegate = self
    popover?.sourceView = sender
    popover?.sourceRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: sender.bounds.width, height: sender.bounds.height))
    popoverContentController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
    self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Comment: This was my issue as well. So basically if you're setting the source using `barButtonItem` then the popover will only dismiss when tapping that bar button again.